# How to get central point of Google Map?

Tags: java, android

I have been developing Android application and I can't make 1 thing - my application uses Google Maps (MapView), and one uses zoom elements for increase/decrease scale of Map. And I need to get center of Map - for example, I can move or increase the Map and than I need to get the central point. I know there is method setCenter() of MapController, but how can I get central point? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mymapView.getCenter();
```

See this ....

http://android-er.blogspot.com/2009/11/mapview-to-center-on-current-location.html

Answer (score 0):

```
public GeoPoint getMapCenter()
```

Returns the current center-point position of the map, as a GeoPoint (latitude and longitude).